# How to set QPixmap in a specific coordinates of QLabel?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to display an image in a `QLabel` in a specific position with covering a particular area so that I can use the rest of the `QLabel` part by other images. By the following, I was able to display image with my set size.

```
QPixmap pix("....image_path..../image.png");
ui->label->setPixmap(pix);
int width = 300;
int height = 320;
ui->label->setPixmap(pix.scaled(width,height));
```

But I am curious to know how to set the position of Image in `QLabel`. Are the any function in `Qt` by using which I can set my image coordinates in a `QLabel`?

Appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure that this is the intended way to use QPixmap with QLabel. I would rather go with a separate label for each image and either arrange the labels in a layout, or position them manually using QWidget::move. See here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#pos-prop

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by painting a new pixmap in layers. Pseudo code

```
QPixmap map;
QPainter p(&map)
p.drawImage(w1,h1,img_1)
...
p.drawImage(wn,hn,img_n)
label.setPixmap(map)
```

Comment: Does `img_1` mean a `QImage` type image? And it's showing an error saying `variable 'QPainter p' has initializer, but incomplete type` in the line `QPainter p(&map)`.

Comment: img_1 should be a qimage of one of the images you want to display. #include <QPainter> to resolve the second issue

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer, but unfortunately it is not setting the position of Image in `QLabel` :(