# How to set QSpinBox in a particular position of mainwindow.ui interface?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qspinbox

I know how to include `QSpinBox` in user interface by coding.

```
QSpinBox *spinbox= new QSpinBox(this);
```

Now I am looking for such a function by which I can set the `QSpinBox` in a particular position in user interface by giving coordinates value of this position.

I tried a couple of functions, but now one is giving me right solution how I would like to have?

Are there any such function in Qt? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To place a widget in a certain position you must use the `move()` function, keep in mind that the widget should not be contained in any layout

```
spinbox->move(x, y);
```

or:

```
Qpoint p(x, y);
spinbox->move(p);
```

Comment: I am using Qt 5.8.0. The `setPos()` function may not be included in this version. So, It is showing `class 'QSpinBox' has no member named 'setPos'`

Comment: @Sanakum Sorry, I confused, the function is move (), and update my answer. :P

Comment: @Sanakum If you bother to read the feedback you receive, maybe you will find an answer to every how-to-position-something question. What part of my comment was unclear? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46912786/how-to-set-qpixmap-in-a-specific-coordinates-of-qlabel#comment80772807_46912786

Comment: @scopchanov I recommend asking the question in your question, I think it is unnecessary and unproductive to put it as a comment in my answer

Comment: What about flag them both as actual duplicates?

Comment: @scopchanov The question that you comment according to read is how to locate a QPixmap inside a QLabel that for example I use a QImage with QPainter and redraw it, but it is very different to move a widget to a specific position. QPixmap has nothing to do with a QWidget.

Comment: @scopchanov Sorry. I didn't understand your comment. Can you explain what you meant.

Comment: QWidget is directly inherited by 44 classes. Indirectly - who knows. Though this stays the same: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#pos-prop Got the point?